# Passing on rep to the source of your answer

Tags: feature-request, reputation, accepted-answer

There are questions that while not duplicates, are very close to a specific concept I'm familiar with. Therefore I can quickly go find the answer in an older Stack Overflow answer, then write a quick summary, post this old answer, and a link to it.

If my answer is accepted, I feel undeserving of the earned rep. Could I award part or all of the 15 rep to the writer of the old answer? It would be manual and optional. I figured it's too complex and would be considered unfair to do this automatically.

Comment: If you don't want to earn any rep for your answer, mark it as community wiki.

Comment: If you feel you don't deserve a reward for doing the leg-work, make your answer community wiki.

Comment: :| You're right, I don't see enough of those to remember what they're for.

Comment: Rather than throwing reputation away by marking answers CW, why not put it to better use by offering it up in the form of [bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/1288)?

Comment: That's a better idea Bill, since you mention it, I recall it is possible to award bounties to existing answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's sufficient to give credit to the person from whom you originally got the answer. Obviously, this would be done by linking to the original answer and attributing it to the user who posted it. All contributions by users are licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), and all that's required to re-use this content is [proper attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Whether you deserve reputation yourself from posting the answer is something for you to decide.

- If you *don't* think you deserve any reputation, you can always mark your answer "community wiki" by checking the appropriate box at the time of submission. This will prevent the answer from earning you any reputation. (Although [some may debate](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) whether this fits into the intended usage for the community wiki feature.)
- However, I would pose the counter-argument that you *do* deserve whatever reputation the answer nets you, by virtue of the fact that you:

1. Remembered seeing the answer somewhere and knew how to find it,
2. Knew that it did and how exactly it applied to this *other* specific question being asked,
3. Took the time to post it as an answer.

Comment: Indeed, knowing something due to an SE answer is no different than knowing it from any other source.