# Duplicate answers (not questions)

Tags: discussion, support, answers, faq-proposed

What should we do when we find the answer to question A in the answers to question B? For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302753/915501) is copied directly from another answer on Stack Overflow (exact duplicate), but the *question* is clearly not a duplicate. Copy and paste the answer? Link to it? Both?

While copy-paste seems most useful to the reader, it sets off alarms in that part of my brain that hates duplicate code.

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: Related: [Handling answers that build heavily on (or are copied outright from) existing answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112084/handling-answers-that-build-heavily-on-or-are-copied-outright-from-existing-an). If you dig through the Linked and Related sections you may find duplicates there (I didn't, but I didn't exactly look, either).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling answers that build heavily on (or are copied outright from) existing answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112084) [Passing on rep to the source of your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129913/passing-on-rep-to-the-source-of-your-answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy paste, if not by the original person who answered should at the very least be accompanies by a link to the original answer.

If you have found such a duplicate, without attribution, by someone different, by all means comment with a link to the original.

Note that I say "should" and not "must" - all content on the site is licensed as CC with [Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) - this means *on other sites*. Within the SE family of sites, it is not required, but a nice to have.

Answer (score 3):

I quote the answer, with a link.

Done it many times:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/23239/7433

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24341/7433

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21787/7433

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24196/7433

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130264/178438

Note that I try to add more meat to each answer. The answers are 'tailored' for a different question, so I add some extra explanation below.

IMO, [the answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302753/915501) is fine, though he *could* have explained what was going on.