# Is the duplicate answer flags raised for exact copies of answers of different users?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, automatic-flags

In the [10k-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answerduplicateanswerauto) there are flags for duplicate answers. For users without the rep, this is what it looks like:

[image]

In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170238/158100) Martijn states that those flags are system generated to help in detecting undesired behaviour. There is also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160134/how-should-one-respond-to-duplicate-answer-flags) that guides how to handle those flags.

Looking at the current flags I conclude that answers that are an exact copy of the same user are detected. Shouldn't that same flag also be automatically raised if an exact copy of an answer by another user is found? I assume 'almost' exact copies will generate to much false positives?